# Flickering on youtube

Tags: youtube, flicker

All the videos on youtube are flickering on my Ubuntu.

See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUEsg.jpg

This happens with HTML5 enabled and disabled.

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a Thinkpad X61s.

This only happens on Google Chrome.

Comment: I can confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124569

A workaround that did it for me, was starting chrome with this command line parameter:
`--disable-accelerated-compositing`

Comment: your 'edited' (==completely replaced) answer now does work for me. please consider adding another answer instead of 'editing' (replacing the old one) next time. thx

Comment: but anyway, thanks for the workaround and the bug link

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the hardware rendering: I noticed this behaviour when I enabled the flag **“Override Software Rendering List”**, i.e. enabling GPU acceleration on unsupported hardware.

Have a look at *chrome://flags* whether it is enabled for you as well.

<sup><sub>(I have an Intel GMA X3100 graphics card in a Thinkpad x61-7673.)</sub></sup>

Comment: Thanks for this hint.
Unfortunately I did not enable this flag. Also enabling or disabling any other flag regarding the GPU does not have any affect on this problem.

Comment: after the upgrade from Chrome 23 to 24, I’m also facing this problem regardless of my flags! but before the upgrade, it used to depend on that.

Comment: please comment here if you find a relevant bug report in the [Chromium issue tracker](http://crbug.com) THX

Comment: or you may as well file one :)

Comment: for the record, the workaround `--disable-accelerated-compositing` works for me. I must have missed the [relevant issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124569) in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started having trouble with Chrome's video (Mar/Apr 2013, Ubuntu 12.10), but only in YouTube. The sound was still ok, and other sites were fine.

I found similar problems reported on Windows Chrome and loosely followed their instructions to disable the PepperFlash pugin. This has improved things massively. Try:

```
about:plugins
```

- click +
- click disable by the `/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so` entry.

(Maybe this entry could be improved slightly?)
(The [PC mag article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2025340/how-to-fix-jerky-youtube-video-in-google-chrome.html) I found the answer in said something about Google monitoring.)